# Accesing the figure inside the figure to add new plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I have a complicated figure that is composed of 3-4 plots. Those plots are made in outside function; and I use that function in my own script.

The thing is that I want to add one more plot to the existing one. When I try to do that by using "hold on", it adds itself to the wrong place, not into the right plot.

Also, earlier I wanted to change color, thickness and other properties of this second plot - and then I had opened the first function and change those properties there, but for now it doesn't seems to be the proper way to handle this problem. The function can be overwritten when updating MATLAB toolbox. That's why I want to find a solution to handle all of these changes inside my own function.

[image: Here is the example of my problem]

If you have any ideas, thanks for sharing!
Mary

Comment: You say "the rigth plot", "the first" "the second". But we have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. I added also the picture with the comment inside, to show what I really mean. I just want to know how to change one figure plotted inside the other one; and to do that in script; not into GUI. Also, I know that one can set different names to his figures and plot them in the sample plot; and then access them singly in script; but my problem is that I use "outside" function to plot them and I don't want to change that function at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is likely relating this call:

```
 hAllAxes = findobj(gcf,'type','axes');
```

This will return all handles to all axes in the current figure. One of the handles, e.g. `hAllAxes(1)` is the bottom plot (it will always be the same, but as you haven't shown code I can't tell which one).

Then you can always plot selecting the axes:

```
plot(hAllAxes(1),myX,myY);
```

Comment: I deleted my last comment. Everything now works perfectly. In "plot(hAllAxes{1},myX,myY);" there is need to change {} to (), and it works just fine. Thank you very much! I searched for this piece of code two days now... Uhh, that'a a relief. Thank you very much! Now I can modify any plot I want :).